# Arranging rectangles in a circle with equal distance

Tags: trigonometry

*I've originally posted this on StackOverflow and didn't get a lot of responses, since it is more a math question than a programming question. I do hope it is on topic here.*

I'm writing a program that renders mind maps. So far, I've succeeded in drawing the root node and the first level of child nodes around it, in a circle.

This is the code that renders the mind map nodes:

```
const root = data.find((node) => node.parent === undefined);
const level1 = data.filter((node) => node.parent === root.id);
root.x = 0;
root.y = 0;
root.level = 0;

await addMindMapNode(scene, root);
const radius = 2;
const slice = (2 * Math.PI) / level1.length;
for (let i = 0; i < level1.length; i++) {
    const level1node = level1[i];
    level1node.level = 1;
    const angle = slice * i;
    const x = root.x + radius * Math.cos(angle);
    const y = root.y + radius * Math.sin(angle);
    level1node.x = x;
    level1node.y = y;
    await addMindMapNode(scene, level1node);
}
```

You can find the [whole program on CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/drawing-a-mind-map-with-threejs-and-react-part-v-qi17x?file=/src/renderMindMap.js).

The output looks like this (with different number of child nodes, from 1 child to 9 children):

[image: rendered nodes]

As you can see, depending on the number of child nodes, the distribution of the child nodes around the root node in the center looks more or less uneven and not pleasing to the eye, especially with 3, 7 or 9 child nodes.

This is because of the rectangular format of the child node boxes. The center points of the boxes have the exact same distance between them, but the length of the distance (shown as red line segments below) is different, depending on position:

[image: coordinates and angles with 7 child nodes]

I have to find a way to make it so that the red circle sections are equal in size.

So my question is:

**How can I calculate the angle at which to render each purple box so that the distance between each box looks to be the same (i.e. take into account the width and height of each box)?**

Comment: Do you need all rectangles horizontal? Children seems siting in a classroom.

Comment: Did you try turning the whole thing 90 degrees st the first box is right on top? It seems to me that the problem arises from being asymmetric from left to right and I do believe we wouldn’t care as much if it were from top to bottom...

Comment: @sirous yes, the rectangles need to be horizontal, so that the labels of the mind map nodes can be easily read.

Comment: @PrudiiArca thanks for the tip! It does look better if I rotate by -90°, so that's a step in the right direction. At 10 nodes, it starts to look bad, because some nodes then touch each other, but perhaps I can just adjust the radius depending on the number of nodes https://codesandbox.io/s/drawing-a-mind-map-with-threejs-and-react-step-6b-ry26t

Comment: If I understand correctly you want for any number of boxes the orientation looks like it is 8 box, am I write?

Comment: @PatrickHund You are welcome. Making the radius depend on the number of nodes is inevitable imo, if you really want to avoid nodes overlapping. Another possibility would be to introduce another ring, if the number of nodes exceeds a certain threshold...

Answer (score 0):

Comment:

I hope these figures help you. I think you have to consider the line connection the mid points of height of rectangles. In first figure the orientation of 8 books on  circle with diameter 184 and 10 books on circle with diameter 560  with constant width of rectangle is shown. In second figure the orientation of 9 books is shown.

[image]

[image]